# How to change new database name in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I had created crystal report by using x database and i updated it to some other database i.e y (In i had added Some New Columns) by(Verify database and SET DATA SOURCE LOCATION  ). I am Getting the old data which was in x database 
Please give me some help Regarding This

Comment: have you checked whether the database is correctly targetted to new database?

Answer (score 1):

1>wright click on Set Database Location option..

2>After selecting ur existing Database in crystal report select new connection for Database.

3>select new Database and click on update.

4>similarly update ur existing procedures/tables with procedures/tables of new database.